# backbone js - htaccess rewrite rule error

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, backbone.js

i have a problem with my .htacces file, i think.

in it i have the line

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]*)-list\?(.+)$ data/backbone_lists.php?class=$1&$2 [L]
```

the url that comes from backbone js is this:

```
record-list?test=1&test_2=2
```

the problem is that i get a [HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found 15ms] error.
The "backbone lists.php" is definitely there, 
because if I remove the GET Part of the target URL, i get the file

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query parameters aren't directly accessible in RewriteRule ( `\?(.+)` in your expression) and there is a flag, QSA, to append those parameters. Try

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]*)-list$ data/backbone_lists.php?class=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: awesome, that's something that you need to know ^^

many thanks!